# what is the ROS linting solution

Tags: ros, lint, ros2

What's the ros way of linting ros code?

For ros1 I have found roslint but it is unclear to me if this is the recommended way to lint ros code and if it is still maintained/supported (last commit from three years ago).

For ros2 I couldn't find any official lint solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is "the ROS way of linting". For your Python/C++ code you can basically use any standard Python/C++ linter.

In addition (when using ROS 1) I can highly recommend [catkin_lint](https://github.com/fkie/catkin_lint), which checks the package definition and notifies about issues like inconsistent dependency declarations or missing install commands (especially the later can save a lot of time when moving from a devel workspace to installing packages on the robot).

Answer (score 2):

The ROS2 development guide explains the rules used. [Link1](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Contributing/Developer-Guide/) and [Link2](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Contributing/Quality-Guide/)

There is a linter located in `ament_lint` to enforce some rules.
To run the linter automatically as part of the tests of the package (use `BUILD_TEST`):

- depend on `ament_lint_auto` and `ament_lint_common`:

[Src file example Package.xml](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/4c632b30ee1dfb0348be4b66104699f83cf04689/demo_nodes_cpp/package.xml#L33)

```
<test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
<test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>
```

- 2 lines to your CMakeLists: (with BUILD_TEST)

[Src file example CMakeList](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/4c632b30ee1dfb0348be4b66104699f83cf04689/demo_nodes_cpp/CMakeLists.txt#L63)

```
find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
```

Comment: The links are now broken, but this is the correct answer for ROS2.